# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAutocompactionInterval' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, nedb

My database has several duplicates (same _id), even after restarting and using `autoload: true`. This is strange, but I decided to solve it by using the setAutocompactionInterval as is suggested in the [guide in the repository](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb), and the result was simply `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAutocompactionInterval' of undefined`.

```
const Db = require('nedb-promise')
    , curry = new Db({
        filename: 'curry'
        , autoload: true
        , onload: (e) => e && console.err(e)
    })

curry.persistence.setAutocompactionInterval(3600000)
// TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAutocompactionInterval' of undefined
Db.persistence.setAutocompactionInterval(3600000)
// TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAutocompactionInterval' of undefined
Db.curry.persistence.setAutocompactionInterval(3600000)
// TypeError: Cannot read property 'persistence' of undefined
```

I don't know what causes this error. I think I will make a Github issue on `nedb-promise`, but is this because of a misuse? Am I misunderstanding the way it should work? Nobody seems to have this error, according to my Google searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help, datastore loosely follows nedb's implementation. It is not an exact representation, that's instead of going through all these lines of codes:

```
const Db = require('nedb-promise')
    , curry = new Db({
        filename: 'curry'
        , autoload: true
        , onload: (e) => e && console.err(e)
    })
```

If you want to control the underlying datastore, you can create it as regular using the original `nedb` library, and then create a wrapped version:

```
const nedb = require('nedb')
const nedbP = require('nedb-promise')

const ds = nedb(...)
const db = nedbP.fromInstance(ds)

const Datastore = require('nedb')
const nedbPromise = require('nedb-promise')

const store = Datastore({autoload: true, filename: '...'})
const db = nedbPromise.fromInstance(store)
await db.insert(...)
store.persistence.compactDatafile()
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered in https://github.com/jrop/nedb-promise/issues/6

`nedb-promise` doesn't have `persistence` and thus it is undefined, so this problem should be solved by using `nedb` directly.